# How to register regions inside user controls or control templates in RegionManager?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I am using `IRegionManager` to load and navigate to views, I have no problem loading content to my main region in my main view which is loaded with my bootstrapper class but I cant load content to regions inside my loaded views, the region manager does not seem to be registering these regions.

my bootstrapper class:

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return this.Container.Resolve<MainWindowView>();
}

protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}

protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    this.Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<DocumentView>();
    this.Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<EmailView>();
    this.Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<WorkTypeSelectionView>();
}
```

the `DocumentView` is user control with another region the method that runs when the command is triggered is this:

```
private void ViewEmailAction()
{
    NavigationParameters parameters;
    parameters = new NavigationParameters();
    parameters.Add(nameof(this.CurrentEmail), this.CurrentEmail);
    this.regionManager.Regions[this.EmailRegion].RequestNavigate(nameof(EmailView), parameters);
}
```

This throws and exception with the message `"The region manager does not contain the EmailRegion region."`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things going on here:

UserControls:
This should work with not issues whatsoever.  Chances are that you are trying to navigate to a region that is defined in a View that hasn't been loaded yet.  Make sure you are navigating to a region after it has been loaded.  Navigating inside of ViewModel constructors is one of the biggest sources of this problem.  If you want to post your sample to GitHub, I can take a look.

ControlTemplates:
This is a known issue in Prism. Here is your fix:

http://southworks.com/blog/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/

Comment: How do I load a View before navigating to it?

Comment: No, the View that contains the region must be loaded before navigating to that region.

Comment: When I navigate to Views their regions are indeed loaded, but the thing is that this particular view is being instantiated programatically and added to a Collection bound to a container, in this case the region inside this programatically loaded view does not get registered. :(

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot going on there. I can safely say it is an implementation issue.  I cannot suggest a solution without a sample.

Comment: I'll try to put an example together, will contact you then, I appreciate your guidance. keep it up you are awesome!